# groupby issues of not recognizing numeric column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel data that i read in by `pd.read_excel`:

```
Block   Concentration       Name            Replicate
  1                      Array Marker   
  1                      Array Marker   
  1       100.0        Man5GlcNAc2  
  1       33.0         Man5GlcNAc2  
  1       10.0         Man5GlcNAc2  
  1       100.0        Man6GlcNAc2  
  1       33.0         Man6GlcNAc2  
  1        10.0        Man6GlcNAc2  
  1        100.0      Man7GlcNAc2 D1    
  1        33.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1    
  1        10.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1    
  1        100.0     Man7GlcNAc2 D3 
  1         33.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3  
  1         10.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3  
...
...
  2        100.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3    
  2         33.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3    
  2         10.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3    
  2         100.0   Man9GlcNAc2 
  2        33.0     Man9GlcNAc2 
  2        10.0     Man9GlcNAc2 
...
```

the desired output is:

```
Block   Concentration       Name            Replicate
  1                      Array Marker         1
  1                      Array Marker         2
  1       100.0        Man5GlcNAc2            1
  1       33.0         Man5GlcNAc2            2
  1       10.0         Man5GlcNAc2            3
  1       100.0        Man6GlcNAc2            1
  1       33.0         Man6GlcNAc2            2
  1        10.0        Man6GlcNAc2            3
  1        100.0      Man7GlcNAc2 D1          1
  1        33.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1          2
  1        10.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1          3
  1        100.0     Man7GlcNAc2 D3           1
  1         33.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3            2
  1         10.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3            3
...
...
  2        100.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3          1
  2         33.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3          2
  2         10.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3          3
  2         100.0   Man9GlcNAc2               1
  2        33.0     Man9GlcNAc2               2
  2        10.0     Man9GlcNAc2               3
...
```

the code i have is

```
data["Replicate"] = data.groupby(["Block", "Name", "Concentration"]).cumcount()+1
```

which i think makes sense, but the output i got is not the desired output, it is below:

```
Block   Concentration       Name            Replicate
  1                      Array Marker         1
  1                      Array Marker         2
  1       100.0        Man5GlcNAc2            1
  1       33.0         Man5GlcNAc2            1
  1       10.0         Man5GlcNAc2            1
  1       100.0        Man6GlcNAc2            1
  1       33.0         Man6GlcNAc2            1
  1        10.0        Man6GlcNAc2            1
  1        100.0      Man7GlcNAc2 D1          1
  1        33.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1          1
  1        10.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1          1
  1        100.0     Man7GlcNAc2 D3           1
  1         33.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3            1
  1         10.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3            1
...
...
  1        100.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3          1
  1         33.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3          1
  1         10.0    Man8GlcNAc2 D1D3          1
  1         100.0   Man9GlcNAc2               1
  1        33.0     Man9GlcNAc2               1
  1        10.0     Man9GlcNAc2               1
...
  1         100.0   Man5GlcNAc2               2
  1        33.0     Man5GlcNAc2               2
  1        10.0     Man5GlcNAc2               2
 ....
```

the replicate columns is '1' until later down the rows, and I am not sure how it's picking which rows to assign the numbers to. There should be a total of 3 block|concentration|name  combos that are the same, so I need to assign '1,2,3' to each to separate them for later when I use pivot table. I have made the 'concentration' column as string type so being numeric should not be a problem.

Comment: The formatting of that data looks a bit odd.  Are you sure it's being read in correctly?

Comment: @BrenBarn  yeah it's being read in correctly. i typed the data here manually so the formatting looks off. sorry about that

Comment: Why is the block either 1 or 2 in the last row. It looks like you shouldn't be grouping by concentration.

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune i see, i think i used the wrong function to achieve what i wanted.  what function should i use instead?

Comment: By your description, you are actually trying to match on two columns "Block" and "Name". You are considering "Concentration" as varying values of those categories. That's why you are thinking in 3's. For example, there are three different `Man5GlcNAc2` values, you are trying to capture those three changes. Take "Concentration" out of your groups. That will solve most of it, but that still leaves your odd "empty" entries. How are you considering those two sets of three? They are exactly the same.

Comment: You say "There should be a total of 3 block|concentration|name combos that are the same" but that's not the case.

Comment: @Andy Hayden  I am thinking about removing the empty concentration rows and only leave the 3 types: 100, 33 and 10

Comment: @Pierre Lafortunei    i am thinking about removing the empty concentration rows and only leave the 3 types: 100, 33 and 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of function `cumcount()+1` can be used [rolling count](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_count.html) with `moving window=3`:

```
#groupby and set rolling count from column Block
data["Replicate"] = data.groupby(["Block", "Name"])["Block"].transform(pd.rolling_count, window=3)
```

Formatting is very strange. If it isn't problem with copy data to question, you can repair it by casting column `Concentration` to float and striping white-spaces in column `Name` from start and end of text.

```
Block   Concentration       Name            Replicate
  1                      Array Marker   
  1                      Array Marker   
  1       100.0        Man5GlcNAc2  
  1       33.0         Man5GlcNAc2  
  1       10.0         Man5GlcNAc2  
  1       100.0        Man6GlcNAc2  
  1       33.0         Man6GlcNAc2  
  1        10.0        Man6GlcNAc2  
  1        100.0      Man7GlcNAc2 D1    
  1        33.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1    
  1        10.0       Man7GlcNAc2 D1    
  1        100.0     Man7GlcNAc2 D3 
  1         33.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3  
  1         10.0    Man7GlcNAc2 D3
```

```
#convert column Concentration to float
data['Concentration'] = data['Concentration'].astype(float)
#strip first and last whitespaces
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip()

#groupby and set rolling count from column Block
data["Replicate"] = data.groupby(["Block", "Name"])["Block"].transform(pd.rolling_count, window=3)
```

```
    Block Concentration            Name  Replicate
0       1                  Array Marker          1
1       1                  Array Marker          2
2       1           100     Man5GlcNAc2          1
3       1            33     Man5GlcNAc2          2
4       1            10     Man5GlcNAc2          3
5       1           100     Man6GlcNAc2          1
6       1            33     Man6GlcNAc2          2
7       1            10     Man6GlcNAc2          3
8       1           100  Man7GlcNAc2 D1          1
9       1            33  Man7GlcNAc2 D1          2
10      1            10  Man7GlcNAc2 D1          3
11      1           100  Man7GlcNAc2 D3          1
12      1            33  Man7GlcNAc2 D3          2
13      1            10  Man7GlcNAc2 D3          3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove 'Concentration' from your group you will get the expected output.

```
data["Replicate"] = data.groupby(["Block", "Name"]).cumcount()+1
>>> data

    Block Concentration             Name  Replicate
0       1            ''     Array.Marker          1
1       1            ''     Array.Marker          2
2       1         100.0      Man5GlcNAc2          1
3       1          33.0      Man5GlcNAc2          2
4       1          10.0      Man5GlcNAc2          3
5       1         100.0      Man6GlcNAc2          1
6       1          33.0      Man6GlcNAc2          2
7       1          10.0      Man6GlcNAc2          3
8       1         100.0    Man7GlcNAc2D1          1
9       1          33.0    Man7GlcNAc2D1          2
```

Comment: @Jessica Huh? This doesn't have the "empty" which counted 1-7. This question makes no sense.